# Configuring Port for PhpStorm with XAMPP

Tags: xampp, phpstorm

I've followed the following guide to set up PhpStorm with XAMPP.
[Installing and Configuring XAMPP with PhpStorm IDE](http://docshare01.docshare.tips/files/29602/296023499.pdf).

However, I got stuck when I reach the following page. At the `Web server root URL`, when I click open, I did not get the XAMPP page. Instead, I got an IIS page because I've IIS setup and point to `http://localhost`. How can I get the XAMPP page instead? Should I turn off my IIS?

[image]

Comment: And whats wrong?

Comment: You should turn off IIS because Apache in XAMPP can't start on 80 port

Comment: @PavloZhukov Ok. So, that means whenever I try to use this, I should turn off IIS. Is there any other better solution rather than turning IIS on and off everytime i try to use them.

Comment: You can configure Apache in another port and use it in all project

Comment: @PavloZhukov I changed the port for Apache. It's running on port 81.

Comment: Now setup in web root url at the end port number `:81`

Comment: @PavloZhukov Got it. Thanks. Can you put your answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: I think this question has nothing to do with PHPStorm. As it's rather related to multiple web servers, I suggest you change the question title accordingly so other readers can find your question better.